# Can't find a running Android virtual machine on M1 MBPro

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, virtual-machine, apple-m1

Device info: MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020), Monterey 12.0.1

Virtual machine info: Nexus 6P API 31, Pixel 5 API 31

Description: I try to run a Flutter project on the Android platform. My Android Virtual Machine can run with the S image (S2 does not work well and the VM can't run with it). However after refresh, I can't find my running VM in the list. [device list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxDyM.png) I try to run both of the VMs but AS shows error like this [error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hH1W.png) And I try to run ADB on 127.0.0.1, still does not show. Please let me know to add other details. I also try to run directly in the device list, but after I run my VMs it still shows , and after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by:

```
Open Android Studio.
Go to AVD Manager.
In the Actions column, for the respective AVD,  click on Stop.
This will stop all the Emulator and then you can restart it from the command 
line.
```

OR

```
 delete the lock files of AVD.
```

OR

```
You would find the following 3files in /.andoroid/avd/(Your Device).avd 
of the user root directory. Then, delete them.

 cache.img
 hardware-qemu.ini.lock
 multiinstance.lock
```

Comment: I do this every time but it still happens still... <no device selected>.

Comment: the .gradle folder under project root or the gradle folder under the android folder?

Comment: In a Mac .android/avd/'NAMEOFAVD.avd directory something like this...

Comment: didn't find it...does this directory exist in a Flutter project? anyway I did delete the lockfile in /Flutter/bin/cache folder

Comment: yeah inside flutter, there should be android folder...

Comment: I find the avd folder under .android. but I don't find the lockfile under either the cache folder or the avd folder... I also have lockfile under flutter project folder but it doesn't seem to relate to avd.

Comment: sorry , AVD is under android studio folder. In a Mac .android/avd/'NAMEOFAVD.avd directory  and delete lock file present there.

Comment: there is a multiinstance.lock file in my avd folder. I delete it and there is no other lockfile present. It still doesn't show the device.

Comment: Please avoid conversations in comments, and move this to [chat].